# What is HTML formatted data

Tags: html, server, client

I have a project i’m working on and i’m allowed to use React and express. But rules are not to use any Html formatted data being exchanged between client and server. What is exactly meant by no Html formatted data. FYI, i plan on using json data to be sent between client and server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML formatted data is a data that you get from HTML, for example: input type, hidden value, etc which you can retrieve using HTTP/REST method such as GET, POST on it's back end. JSON is not HTML formatted data, CMIIW.